# How can I profile only my code in Python or IPython?

Tags: python, ipython, profiler, line-profiler

I'm familiar with the `%prun` magic command in IPython that uses the Python `profile` module. However, I'd like to only profile my code. That is, I'd like to see which are the slowest lines in my Python code, not the lines buried deep in some external package I'm using that get called often and therefore appear to take the most time. How can I do this?

Comment: There's [*always this method*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771). Just ignore the lines that are not in your code. The difference between this and the line profiler is that it tells you *why* the time is being spent, not just *where*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a little more Googling it seems that `line_profiler` is the answer: https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler

```
import line_profiler
%load_ext line_profiler
```

Then just

```
%lprun -f function_i_want_to_profile function_i_want_to_run()
```

Answer (score 1):

While `line_profiler` works, it adds a lot of overhead and you need to put `@profile` all over the place.

You can sort the output of `%prun` in all kinds of ways. One of them is by module name:

```
%prun -s module my_func()
```

So choosing your file names accordingly, like starting with an underscore, would put your files in beginning of the list `%prun` shows.